# Can't open any Dialog Box

Tags: windows-xp

As of now, my computer (running Windows XP) cannot open some windows, such as the Display Properties, Add or Remove Programs, etc. ...

A program, named `rundll32.exe` stops its process when the computer is booting.  It shows a Dialog Box, showing that the process is unfortunately stopped.

I also found out (by testing), that rundll32.exe is actually the process when opening some Dialog Boxes / Windows.  I try to open the Display Properties, and the rundll32.exe process appears at the Task Manager.

**What could be the cause of the problem here?**

Comment: Did you try to run the OS in safe mode (F8 on boot up) ?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that thing, but still, nothing works (no dialog boxes) ...

Comment: You might try to run malwarebytes and using Disk Cleanup Wizard - From the Start button menu, choose All Programs→Accessories→System Tools→Disk Cleanup or killdll. Take care with XP and internet, because XP is not more supported(patched).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had found the solution!

The problem is on the `rundll32.exe`, which is present in `C:\Windows\System32`.

I went to its file location, and saw that the program is there, but the icon looks a bit different. The icon looks like the icon from Adobe Acrobat Reader, so that means, my computer got hit by a Trojan virus.

What I did to fix the problem is I downloaded the original file from the internet, and replaced the harmful file with the original file. I rebooted the computer, and it is now working fine.

Comment: What's with the downvote? I had already updated my answer.